# Node Js , Router

Tags: mysql, node.js

I send data to jade page from router like this:

```
router.get('/allUsers', function(req, res, next) {

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT name,surname,teacher_id,lesson_id,reg_Date FROM maven_test.student",
            function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;

            res.render('users', { student_data:result });

        });
    });    
});
```

And I want set this data to table like this:

```
#studentDataDiv
  center
    table#studentTable(cellspacing='2', cellpadding='2', width='100%', border='1px solid green')
      thead
        tr

          th Student name
          th Student surname

      tbody
        - each item in student_data
        tr

          td=item.name
          td=item.surname
```

But I got error like this:

> This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
>   GET /users/allUsers 500 2104.946 ms - 143

How can I do this operation?

Comment: I improved the formatting of your code. Not sure about the Jade stuff though. Please ensure that I didn't break anything.

Comment: then can u tell me how should i get data from router and set it table?

Comment: No, I don't know that.